# Removing rows when some values match and some do not

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

```
ID Amount Previous 
1  10     15
1  10     13
2  20     18
2  20     24
3  5      7
3  5      6
```

I want to remove the duplicate rows from the following data frame, where ID and Amount match. Values in the Previous column do not match. When deciding which row to take, I'd like to take the one where the Previous column value is higher.

This would look like:

```
ID Amount Previous 
1  10     15
2  20     24
3  5      7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is `distinct` on the columns 'ID', 'Amount' (after `arrange`ing the dataset) while specifying the `.keep_all = TRUE` to get all the other columns that correspond to the distinct elements in those columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    arrange(ID, Amount, desc(Previous)) %>%
    distinct(ID, Amount, .keep_all = TRUE)
#   ID Amount Previous
#1  1     10       15
#2  2     20       24
#3  3      5        7
```

---

Or with `duplicated` from `base R` applied on the 'ID', 'Amount' to create a logical `vector` and use that to subset the rows of the dataset

```
df2 <- df1[with(df1, order(ID, Amount, -Previous)),]
df2[!duplicated(df2[c('ID', 'Amount')]),]
#  ID Amount Previous
#1  1     10       15
#3  2     20       24
#5  3      5        7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Amount = c(10L, 
10L, 20L, 20L, 5L, 5L), Previous = c(15L, 13L, 18L, 24L, 7L, 
6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```